# Make file command not executed in windows console

Tags: makefile, mingw, conemu

I am using makefile to build my code for boost cpp application. When makefile get executed it shows following message

```
g++ -c -Wall -I/c/MinGW/include/ -lboost_system -lws2_32 Timer_async.cpp -o Timer_async.o
```

and throws following error

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:15: Timer_async.o] Error 1
```

but if I run this makefile generated command from shell prompt

```
g++ -c -Wall -I/c/MinGW/include/ -lboost_system -lws2_32 Timer_async.cpp -o Timer_async.o
```

Program builds properly.

My make file is as

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lboost_system -lws2_32
INCLUDES=-I/c/MinGW/include/
SOURCES=Timer_async.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) $(INCLUDES) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specify both `$(SOURCES)` and `$(EXECUTABLE)` as dependencies to all?  What is that adding that the `$(EXECUTABLE)` rule isn't achieving?

The `#include` is failing (that's what the diagnostic message seems to indicate) because the target file cannot be found. You have used the `-I` flag incorrectly.  That will only influence how `includedFile.c` is located; it has no effect on `<includedFile.c>`.

Your conclusion "Makefile command not executed" (and I have no idea what a "Makefile command" is) was unwarranted.  `make` did exactly what it was supposed to.

Comment: I used this standard makefile form http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/ and added my support for INCLUDE macro.

Comment: The error is executing same line from shell vs executing it from make. So i don't think this is due to -I flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is may be how conemu handles file paths. after changing make file to following more specific

```
CFLAGS = -c -I/c/MinGW/include
2
3  hello: Timer_async.o
4
5  Timer_async.o: Timer_async.cpp
6          g++ $(CFLAGS) Timer_async.cpp
7
8  clean:
9          rm Timer_async.o
```

I was still getting errors but after adding double quotes in path all errors were corrected.

My modified make file is

```
CFLAGS = -c -I"/c/MinGW/include"
2
3  hello: Timer_async.o
4
5  Timer_async.o: Timer_async.cpp
6          g++ $(CFLAGS) Timer_async.cpp
7
8  clean:
9          rm Timer_async.o
```